# plt.scatter error 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'sqrt' after running successfully

Tags: python, scatter-plot

I have a code similar to the one below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = [1,2,3]
b = [3,4,5]
plt.scatter(a,b)
plt.grid()
plt.yscale("linear")
plt.show()
```

The first couple times I run it, it works fine but afterwards it gives me the error:

```
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'sqrt'
```

which seems to be located somewhere deep in pyplot rather than it being a problem with my code. Is this something others have encountered?

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. Can you add the full trace of your error?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a Jupyter Notebook with `%matplotlib widget`, it can be due to an interactive plot that hasn't been switched off. Try hitting the blue off button and try again.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I used Jupyter notebooks with `%matplotlib notebook` and interactive 3d plots. I replaced it with `%matplotlib inline`, restarted the kernel and it worked.